# "would have been" without if-part but with "in retrospect"

Tags: grammar, conditionals, conditional-perfect

I struggle with the following sentence:

> In retrospect, it would have been an interesting experience.

The *it* refers to something in the sentence before:

> I have never ascended Mount Everest because I was afraid of it.

I am not a native speaker and I only know the phrase "would have been" in combination with a conditional III sentence. But since there is no *if* or one of its replacement words like *should* for example, I struggle to identify the underlying grammar rules. Can someone please explain to me, which grammar rule does here apply?

Thanks!

Comment: The context of the previous sentence is needed to understand this sentence.

Comment: I added the sentence

Comment: The context of the previous sentence (or a similar one) is needed to license the (first highlighted) sentence here. Referential _it_'s etc (not non-referential ones as in _It's raining_) need an antecedent (usually coming before the pronoun, as the name implies – perhaps in the preceding sentence). The rule 'nearest _sensible_ noun phrase actually appearing, or retrievable' applies, so that 'it' in 'it would have been ...' refers back to '[an attemt at] the climbing of Everest', not 'Everest'.

Comment: It's simply not a good sentence. "in retrospect" means after it was done. Here the subjunctive *would* merely implies the conditional. *[If I had done it,] it would have been an interesting experience [when] in retrospect. The joy would have come afterwards, should the fear ever disappear*

Comment: @vectory I thought "in retrospect" means something like "looking back into the past". "If I had done something in the past, it would have been an interesting experience." But the "If I had done something in the past" part is only implicitly given in the preceding sentence. Honestly, I don't get why this is a bad sentence yet. Maybe because I am not a native speaker :D

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand that this it refers to [an attempt]. But what does this have to do with my question regarding the conditional III construction without if? Sorry if I just misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Yes it means "looking back", "in hindsight" indeed, but there is nothing to look back to that they have done. One could recoup and say they actively had fear, and that the fear of ascending the K2 wasn't so bad. Nevermind that's an obvious understatement, it still subsumes the object of fear under the hindsight. On the one hand this looks like a logical fallacy and thus *simply not good*, but on the other hand it resolves my last notion above, insofar the fear could make it exiting, for lack of a better word.